# ufw ubuntu blocks iregularly ftp_connect() PHP

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ftp, ufw

I am writing a simple php app which connects and brings data from an ftp server. The issue is that I get a successful connection some times and others they get blocked. This is my code which runs in Ubuntu with Apache

```
$ftpConn = ftpConnect($ftpHost, $ftpUser, $ftpPassword);


function ftpConnect($host, $user, $password) {
    $ftpConn = ftp_connect($host,21,3)or die("Couldn't connect to $host");
    $login = ftp_login($ftpConn, $user, $password);
    // check connection
    if ((!$ftpConn) || (!$login)) {
        echo 'FTP connection has failed again! Attempted to connect to ' . $host . ' for user ' . $user . '.';
    } else {
        return $ftpConn;
    }
}
```

ufw status numbered as below:

```
[ 1] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 20/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 3] 21/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 4] 40000:50000/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 5] 990/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 6] 9822                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 7] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 8] 20/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[ 9] 21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[10] 40000:50000/tcp (v6)       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[11] 990/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
[12] 9822 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I am not sure why this occurs. any advice is welcome

Comment: 3 seconds connect timeout? ... Why not try the `ftp_connect` without the last 2 parameters, which defaults to `21` and `90` respectively.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Yes indeed I agree with you. Sadly I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Does `$host` have any trailing slashes, by chance? Also, maybe check the return of the connect first, and _then_ do login if connect was good. With current handling, you could be using a bad connect reference with login.

Comment: Yes it returns as expected and login also returns as expected. I tried to disable the firewall and it has been suspected there is no mistake. However I do not want to get my server without ufw.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks a lot for your help. I finally fixed it. The issue was nothing but blocked ports. So the ftp server (I did not know this) has been configured to make use of ports in a range from 30000 to 61000. Being said that I had configure my local firewall to allow 40000:50000/tcp. Thus, it sometimes worked sometimes it did not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ftp server I was trying to connect was configured to use 30000:61000/tcp ports while passive connecting so my local firewall was allowing a few of them and denying some others. The solve? increasing the range of allowed ports.

Thanks!

Comment: Its 2020. You should not still be using FTP. If you *really* must, then the right way to fix the problem is to use passive mode - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php

Comment: Amazing! Your suggestion is much appreciated, sadly it is a pre-requirement based on an already built system. Nevertheless, I am taking this to my list of "must do". Thanks symcbean!